# Hot to build a SEO friendly JavaScript menu that is used in over 20 pages

Tags: javascript, seo

I built a javascript menu list from a xml file and has used it as the navigation menu in over 20 pages.I used jQuery's ajax functoinality to implement this,the reason I used this technique was because if there is an update in the menu list I only have to edit the xml file for the changes to reflect in the menu list. I only realized later the technique I have used is not SEO friendly,since SE doesnt index dynamic Javascript content.Saying that I have provided a fall back for users that have diabled their java script by linking the xml file to a object tag in a noscript tag

```
                    <noscript>
                    <div>
                        <object data="menu/Menu.xml" type="all"></object>
                    </div>
                   </noscript>
```

Im not too sure if this is SEO friendly.

So my question really is how do one go about creating a menu list that is user friendly and that can be updated easily? If questions similar to mine have been answered before please point me to the links.I have done some searching and was not happy with the results I found but Im still looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not SEO friendly. Anyway, you should be using a server side programming language like PHP's includes or Server Side Includes to do this.